# Custom error setting being ignored for locations denied in the web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config, custom-errors

In a ASP.Net 4 and MVC2 application we have an odd configuration error.

The web.config looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="blockedpath">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Visiting the blocked location is correctly denied, but gives a verbose error message from IIS that we don't want.

Why doesn't it serve up the configured custom error?

Can we control what page it does serve up when page access is denied by config?

Comment: If I understand well, you ask for the loginUrl="PageOnNotLogedin.aspx", the page the user must go when its not logged in ? correct ?

Comment: We're not using the web.config to control that but we're basically similar. However that page is the result for 401 (i.e. you can log in if you provide the right user) as opposed to 403 (your user can't see this). 403 forbidden errors shouldn't redirect to a login form.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx) blog post, IIS7 is trying to be helpful and likes to steal your custom errors pages and replace them with its own.

Open the *Error Pages* feature in IIS and click *Edit Feature Settings* on the right hand menu. Set the *Detailed errors option* to have IIS pass through whatever errors you serve up from ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks. I found that you can also override that setting in config using the `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"` mentioned by @Kev in his answer. Unfortunately it still returns the generic error.

Answer (score 0):

If this is IIS7 then it looks like IIS is hijacking the response. Try this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cheers, I tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference in my case.

Comment: you can see it in a fresh .Net 4 IIS7 app, just add the deny page to the web.config and visit it.